# How would one return a MySQL query's completion status with mysql.connector?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

To start off, here is an example of what I mean by the 'completion status'. This is a query run via MySQL's CLI

```
    mysql> USE DATABASE1;
    Database changed
```

The line,`Database Changed` is what I am after. The mysql.connector lib for Python only returns the result of queries that return tables of data from what I've seen so far (I will preface this by saying that I am a beginner to SQL in general, so admittedly I have not tried everything out there).

I am trying to create a MySQL gui-based front end as part of a project, so I am trying to replicate the MySQL CLI 'experience',so to speak, to as high a degree as possible. So stuff like getting out such output text is imperative

For instance,

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', password = key)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute('USE DATABASE1')
for i in mycursor:
    print(i)
```

Returns... nothing (Understandable, iterating on the cursor would only provide table data after all). I want to find a way to extract `Database Changed` through mysql.connector. I've scoured through the docs but can't find any method that would yield me such a thing. Is there a way to eke it out?

Answer (score 0):

You could do (I did after reading this [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html))

When you only want to print database changes when they happen, you can do something like this:

```
import mysql.connector 
from mysql.connector import errorcode

_current_database = ''
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'localhost', 
     user = 'test', password = 'test', auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

def Execute_MySQL_and_print_result(sqlstatement):
    global _current_database
    global cnx
    try:
       mycursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
       mycursor.execute(sqlstatement)
       if (cnx.database != _current_database):
           _current_database = cnx.database
           print("Database changed to: ", cnx.database)
       j=1
       for i in mycursor:
           print(j, i)
           j=j+1
    except  mysql.connector.Error as err:
       print("OOPS, something went wrong: ", err.errno)
       print(err.msg)

Execute_MySQL_and_print_result('USE TEST')
Execute_MySQL_and_print_result('SHOW DATABASES')
Execute_MySQL_and_print_result('USE TEST')
Execute_MySQL_and_print_result('SHOW DATABASES')
Execute_MySQL_and_print_result('SELECT * FROM nonexistingTable')
```

output:

```
Database changed to:  test
1 ('information_schema',)
2 ('sakila',)
3 ('test',)
4 ('world',)
1 ('information_schema',)
2 ('sakila',)
3 ('test',)
4 ('world',)
OOPS, something went wrong:  1146
Table 'test.nonexistingtable' doesn't exist
```

I added the numbers before the database names to make it clear when the second `SHOW DATABASE` is starting output.

Note: The second `USE TEST` has no output, because active database did not change.

Comment: Hardcoding is an approach yes, but the problem is that the user is free to input any query they want in the GUI front-end and get the results accordingly.

Showing that the database changed when some arbitrary command is given wouldn't work. Hence, I was asking if there was a way to squeeze out those status messages/completion status messages through some method of sorts

Comment: I am not hardcoding, because the name of the database you changed to is fetched using `cnx.database`. when you change `USE TEST` to `USE NONEXSTINGSOMEHTING` you will see the difference.

Comment: I am confused though. Wouldn't this only work if the only query ever inputted is `USE DATABASE1` or something similar? If I want the user to input any query, how can I show that the database has been changed ONLY when the user inputs a query that changes the database?

Comment: I did an EDIT on my answer.

Comment: Problem is that I am an absolute beginner to SQL. While this lets me handle database changes, I wanted to account for other commands similar to database changes as well, in that they only show status messages (in MySQL CLI) as opposed to a table. I am not aware if there are other queries that do stuff like that (Since I am a beginner) . Is there a way to account for ANY query that only shows a status message? I would like to extract status messages for any arbitrary 'status-message-only' query

Comment: Learn (My)SQL first, ask again when you are no longer a beginner in SQL. your question is currently like driving a car, without having followed driving lessons, and asking how to drive to Moscow from Paris.

Comment: the last example on [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) page shows a solution similar to the above .